# Create a javascript object called Patient that has following properties:

Tags: javascript

1. firstName, 
       2. lastName
       3 age
       4. dob
       5.phoneNumber

   and following methods:
       1. getFirstName()
       2. getLatName()
       3. getFullName()
       4. getAge()
       5. setAge
       6. getDob()
       7. setDob()
       8. getPhoneNumber()
       9. setPhoneNumber()

and has constructor that takes firstName and lastName as parameters

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! StackOverflow expects you to [**try to solve your own problem first**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), and we also [**don't answer homework questions**](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
 var patient = {
   firstName: '',
   lastName: '',
   age: 0,
   dob: 0,
   phoneNumber: 0,
   getFirstName: function(){
      return this.firstName;
   },
   getLatName: function(){
       return this.lastName;
   },
   getFullName: function(){
       return this.firstName + ' '+ this.lastName;
   },
   getAge: function(){
       return this.getAge;
   },
   setAge: function(age){
       this.age = age;
   },
    getDob: function(){
       return this.dob;
   },
    setDob: function(dob){
       this.dob = dob;
   },
    getPhoneNumber: function(){
       return this.phoneNumber;
   },setPhoneNumber: function(phone){
      this.phoneNumber = phone;
   }
};
```